# Parsing HTML tags with Smarty

Tags: php, html, html-parsing, smarty

Is there I simple way to get contents of a `<h1>` tag from a html file, using PHP (or Smarty), on the server side?

Background is that I need to do some SEO on a legacy Smarty based PHP site, with bunch of content pages with **no head section defined**.

I.e., the main `index.php` page loads a shared `index.tpl` template which contains the `<head>` section along with `<title>` and meta description tags **for all pages**, and then just grabs the content from individual `pXXX.html`, based on an `id` parameter in the url. Each "content" page has an `<h1>` tag where the relevant title is stored, but the page title remains fixed all the time.

Since there is too many of them to edit each of them individually, I wanted to see if I could get their each by parsing the page on request. I guess I could make a script which would do some batch processing, but I am looking for a quick solution which wouldn't modify these content pages.

I am open to other suggestions, also. To be honest, I never used Smarty before, so I might be missing something here.

Comment: h1 tag content is hardcoded in pXXX.tpl ?

Comment: @soju: yes, those templates are plain old html files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_match('~<h1>(.+)</h1>~', file_get_contents('original_file.html'), $result);
var_dump($result[1]);
```

Comment: You'd better not have two h1 tags in the template ;-)

Comment: Since this is a SEO related topic, there shouldn't be more than one h1 ;)

Answer (score 1):

Well, in index.php you could :

- get content of pXXX.html in a var (before loading index.tpl)
- create a smarty var, for example $content
- parse content to get h1 title
- create a smarty var, for example $title
- modify index.tpl to display $title and $content